# Using GOOGLE TRANSLATE in WebView. "Desktop" working, "Mobile" not working

Tags: java, android, webview, google-translate

I managed to use translate.google.com by passing arguments into the URL and then loading page into my webView. However, passing arguments works only if I set the page into "desktop" mode

- http://translate.google.com/#ja/en/text_to_translate

How can I do the same with "mobile" mode

- http://translate.google.com/m/translate/

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that as well I guess. I have not tried it on mobile but tried on desktop browser in mobile mode. Try to hit this http://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=text_to_translate

Comment: Well done! I was sure that it is possible but didn't know how to construct the hyperlink. Another think is, that when I use link provided by you, I can see 2 input text fields. Is it possible to have only one?

Comment: I thinks thats as designed behavior on mobile :(. You can also mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue by the way :)

Comment: In the browser there are also 2 TextViews. But if I use this link: http://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ja&ie=UTF-& (without the text to translate) there is only one. Please confirm here if you know, or don't know how to solve that, just to make me sure. Also, I have one question with bounty on it, maybe you will be able to resolve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933172/challange-custom-animation-of-viewpager-change-height-of-choosen-elements-vie

Comment: yes you are right. This is exactly what I also observed and as such could not come up with any immediate workaround. Will surely add comment as soon as I come across any solution/workaround

Answer (score -2):

use this link directly , it will open in mobile view and will show the text in box

https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/hello